# So I've mad a hug command but I would like it so it wouldnt @ the person being hugged

Tags: tags, command, member

So I've made a hug command that goes like <3hugs @thisperson (<3 is my prefix) and it will come out as @thisotherperson hugs @thisperson.  And I would like it not to @ the person getting hugged. because I want it so that if the bot gets hugged it responds. However because of the @ it goes on a loop (which I fixed) but it says the response twice. I hope that made sense. Also, I am very new to coding and making a bot :p

I've tried using different terms, but ultimately i dont know what exactly i should use and i cant find it anywhere.

```
case 'hug':
        if(!args[1]){
            message.reply('who is this hug for?')

        }else{
            message.channel.send(`${message.author} huggies you, ${member} !!!!!`);

        }
            break;   


bot.on('message', msg=> {
  if (msg.isMentioned(bot.user)) {
    msg.channel.sendMessage('AWWWWWWW!! THANKIES!! Love you too!!');
```

}
}); //... this is the code i use for the bots response

So I expected that if perhaps the bot gets chosen to be hugged in the <3randhug then it would have its own response. and it works fine, because the bot only gets @ once. However, when a person choses to hug the bot it gets @ twice.

Like

Sofira: <3 hug @cloudbot
Bot: Awwwwwww
Bot:@Sofira huggies you @cloudbot
Bot: awwwwwww

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so you want the second "awwww" to not happen, right?  Is there a way you can compare two different message authors?  Like making the "awwww" block conditional. As an example, making it so that instead of just replying with "awwww" to every message that mentions it, making it only reply with awww to a member other than itself mentioning it. Also, without a conditional statement like that, even just a message like "@CloudBot" will still cause the whole "aww" response.

Comment: How would I even do that?

Comment: Well, I'm just assuming this is a Discord bot made with javascript?  You'd have to look into documention, but surely there's a way to check. Maybe like an "if ${message.author} != "@CloudBot#0000", of course replacing the zeros with it's number.

Comment: Oh yeah makes sense. And yes I'm using discord.js

Comment: Hope it helps!  And the syntax I gave a minute ago might be wrong. I have literally zero JS knowledge.

Comment: I had to use if (message.author.bot) return; but it worked. Thankies to you I was able to find what i needed ^Y^

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction!!  If you wouldn't mind, could you accept the answer?